# If I buy something on Amazon, at what point before I buy it can I see when the estimated delivery date is?

Tags: amazon

If I buy something on Amazon, at what point before I buy it can I see when the estimated delivery date is?

E.g. can you show a pic of where in the process it is?

Because sometimes I find I buy it and then I am told the delivery is in 2 weeks, when I was hoping for delivery in a day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the case[what barlop said], unless the product has the "See All Buying Options" button instead of the "Add to Cart" button. However, once you click the See All button it will show an estimated delivery date with each buying option.

Answer (score 0):

It's between the price and the "add to basket" button

[image]